# Como actualizar archivos específicos en un repositorio en remoto en GitHub desde uno local sin traer el resto de archivos al repositorio local?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Hola amigos buenas a todos.
Estoy realizando un código con GitPython que su función es actualizar un archivo en un repositorio remoto en github pero sin bajar los otros archivos subidos por otros usuarios

específicamente lo que quiero hacer es subir un archivo y reemplazarlo por otro con el mismo nombre pero con cambios sin tener que bajar el resto de archivos q se van actualizando igual es decir no tener q hacer git pull y bajar todo cada vez q se vaya actualizar

intente usar git fetch para q no se fusione el remoto con con el local pero no me deja subir el cambio especifico del archivo solamente

si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0):

Si hiciste fetch, entonces debes poder trabajar sobre la rama remota, para no tocar tus ramas locales. Digamos que el remoto es `origin` y que la rama que te interesa es `abc`:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/abc
# en este punto git te va a decir que estas trabajando en "detached HEAD¨, todo gud
# haces el cambio del archivo que necesitas
git add el-archivo
git commit -m "Un cambio que quiero hacer"
git push origin @:abc
```

Y listo!